# I'm having trouble embedding HSQLDB into a simple Java (Eclipse) project

Tags: java, database, hsqldb, classnotfoundexception

After reading up on some options (sqlite, derby etc...), I've decided to throw down with HSQLDB. I've downloaded it, read up on it and followed a 'hello world' type intro to it, and am now stuck.

I believe that you have to put the hsqldb.jar file in the src folder, so I did exactly that. Then I made a reference to the package with Eclipse by going into Run -> Run Configurations, then going into the Classpath tab, then clicking User Entries, then add External Jar, and selecting hsqldb.jar.

I get this :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Here's my code :

```
package mysqlite;

import java.sql.*;

public class myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");

            String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:db";
            String user = "aUser";
            String password = "";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());           
        }
    }
}
```

I understand it's unable to find a class, but I thought that was what the hsqldb.jar provided.

Comment: ignore the package name lol, this started as an investigation into sqlite.

Comment: 2nd comment : upon going back into the classpath area, under user entries, the jar I referenced is no longer listed.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Turns out my question boils down to 'how do you include a jar file properly in Eclipse'. I found the answer here http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29 Funny how typing out the question really helps you realize where you went wrong. Leaving this all here in case anyone else might need it.

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not have to put it into src folder. src is for source files (*.java). You have to add this jar into your classpath:  click on project properties, choose "Java build path", select tab "Libraries" and add the jar here.

The jar can be stored anywhere in your file system. Sometimes people create lib directory under project home and put all 3rd party dependencies there.

Comment: Tried it that way too, works well. I think part of my confusion is / was classpath vs buildpath.

Comment: @jason , if it works well, you can accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the .jar here:

```
<YOUR_JAVA_HOME>\jre\lib\ext
```

Comment: Im curious how that would play out when you go to distribute the program. Would you need to provide the jar separately with your app? Or does it get somehow bundled with your app? What if you have multiple unrelated projects and you store numerous unrelated .jars in there? So much more experimenting to do...

Comment: This needs a downvote actually, you will find out why eventually

Comment: You would be better off putting the .jar in your classpath as @AlexR instructed... Putting it here is just a quick and dirty way to do it that worked for me when I was playing around with a database recently.